# How to load a static google map with a path (polyline)?

Tags: api, url, google-maps, static, path

I have implemented some code that loads an image from a URL upon a listview item being clicked; this has been tested with a 'dummy' image and works without any problem with the image being displayed in an imageview object.

However, what I really want to do is to load a Static Google Map with Paths (polyline) via URL, but for some reason this is not working and I hope that someone here will be able to tell me what is wrong with my URL:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397
```

According to the Google documentation http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ I believe that my URL should work, because an image witha path only requires the size attribute (i.e. all others are optional).

When I try to test load my URL via a web-browser I receive an Error 403 in Google Chrome telling me that the googleapis website requires a log in.  Is this the API key?  I have an API key that I've previously used for a non-static google map and I copy/pasted this key from the map's xml into my URL (using the key= attribute), but again this was not successful.

I've tried searching on google and this forum, but it seems that no-one has had this problem before - or maybe I'm just really bad at searching :(  But hopefully someone can assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the required `sensor` [parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html#Sensor).

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397&sensor=false
```

Comment: You must take care to treat long URL paths (current limit is 2048 bytes). If you need to use long URLs, you should use polyline encoding, as described in [Google Maps Static API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Paths) and the algorithm format is explained in [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm)

Comment: sensor parameter no longer required.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Moreinfo

Answer (score 5):

This requirement is fairly new, but yes, you are missing the API key.

Just as you added the parameters `&size=` or `&path=`, at some point you need to have a `&key=`parameter. So for your example it would look like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&key=ENTER-YOUR-API-KEY&path=40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397
```

hope that helps