# How do I place a static google image map url in an img tag?

Tags: image, google-maps, static

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#quick_example

> Notice that you don't need to do anything "special" to get this image
>   to show up on the page. No JavaScript is required. **All we needed to do
>   was create a URL, and place it within an  tag**. You can place a
>   Google Google Static Maps API anywhere on your webpage where you can
>   place an image.

How do I place the URL within an  tag?

Comment: Please refer to this, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874173/how-to-load-a-static-google-map-with-a-path-polyline?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example running from

[Quick example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#quick_example)

Here In this example I have not used any key but you have to use key as given in documentation to avoid any errors

```html
<img width="600" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284">
```

Comment: I've tried this... `<img width="600" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap">` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it to work. I needed a static map API key. I had a different map API key?

Comment: If this answer works, close this as accepted answer as instructed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)