# How to takesnapshot of googlemap in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

please i am new to flutter googlemaps., I would like to take a screenshot of googlemap showing directions between two markers, currently i used the screenshot plugin but this only captured a blank image. Please help a brother.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [takeSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/takeSnapshot.html) method from the **GoogleMapController** class of the [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package. This method returns an image bytes of the map.

Here's the [github link](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/snapshot.dart) for the sample code.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: It doesn't work in Flutter web! Error: ""Error: UnimplementedError:
takeSnapshot() has not been
implemented.""

Comment: google_maps_flutter package only works on Android and iOS at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to use "Map Static API" which gives you a jpg image (with markers and anything you want) passing the lat and long.

Link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview

Example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Result:

[image: Static Map]

Comment: But I need to use the polyline feature to draw directions between two point. This cannot be achieved using the static map

Comment: You should read the official Docs as Polygons and Paths are available over Static Map. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874456/3743245